# Как отследить пустое значение при загрузке Excel файла

Tags: c#, excel, entity

Делаю загрузку Excel файла, через OleDb в DataTable.
После нужно загрузить в БД, через Entity.

Как и где правильнее делать проверку на пустые значения в загруженные из Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Если при хотя бы одной ошибочной записи надо отменить всю загрузку - то после загрузки в DataSet, но до преобразования в сущности.

Если ошибочные записи надо просто игнорировать/выводить в лог, а валидные записи при этом импортировать - то в коде преобразования DataRow в сущность, перед добавлением в контекст.